# What is the intuitive explanation of the weights (coefficients) in multiple linear regression?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression

$$y=w_0+w_1x_1+w_2x_2+...+w_nx_n$$

How are the weights interpreted intuitively and geometrically what do the signify
and what is $x_i$ is it a sample or a particular feature's vector?

Comment: The coefficients are not usually *weights* here unless something special is happening

Comment: I have seen the terminology of "coefficients" used in linear equations such as " y = a + b * log(x) + c * sin(x)" and the terminology of "weights" used as in this case where the parameters are *only* used as direct multipliers on independent variables.